# Python newbie - refactor string function

Tags: python

I started learning Python yesterday and one of the challenges on the site I am using is asking to solve this problem below.  While I did solve the problem successfully it looks very amateurish and I would like if someone smart could show a better solution or offer any related advice.  Thanks.

Problem:
Write a function called censor that takes two strings, text and word, as input. It should return the text with the word you chose replaced with asterisks.

My Solution:

```
def censor(text, word):
    text = text.split(" ")
    for i in text:
        if i == word:
            i_index = text.index(i)
            i = "*" * len(i)
            del(text[i_index])
            text.insert(i_index,i)
    text = " ".join(text)
    return text
```

Comment: This is getting downvoted because it is *off-topic* for Stack Overflow. If you have working code but want to know how to improve it, use [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, '*' * len(word))
```

Simple string replace function, pretty much found in any standard library.

Comment: it's weird cuz they said you can use split and join, but this is way easier.  the only thing is you are only replacing the word with one asterisk, but it needs to be '*' * len(word) so if you update your answer i'll accept it, thanks.

Comment: @AshtonMorgan you could just use `'*' * len(word)` as you said in the comments as the replacement string